# Город по умолчанию при использовании kladr

Tags: javascript, кладр

Подскажите, как установить город по умолчанию в строке поиска. Необходимо, чтобы осуществлялся поиск по улице в этом городе.

```
$city.fias('type', $.fias.type.city);
$city.fias('withParents', true);
$street.fias('type', $.fias.type.street);
$street.fias('parentType', $.fias.type.city);
$street.fias('parentId', 7700000000000);
$street.fias('withParents', true);
$building.fias('type', $.fias.type.building);
```

Так не выходит. Поле с улицей остается пустым.